# How to use Python to detect if the USB port has stopped working

Tags: python, ubuntu, usb, raspberry-pi4

There is a USB port on Raspberry Pi 4 (aarch64 Cortex-A72) with OS Ubuntu 22.04 (Linux ubuntu 5.15.0-1026-raspi #28-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Fri Mar 10 14:28:52 UTC 2023 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux).

Due to malfunctions, it happens that after 2-4 hours the port stops working. Specifically, the CH341 inverter stops working.

Logs:

```
[ 98.258711] hub 1-1.3:1.0: USB hub found
[ 98.258882] hub 1-1.3:1.0: 4 ports detected
[ 98.544411] usb 1-1.3.1: new full-speed USB device number 55 using xhci_hcd
[ 98.650582] usb 1-1.3.1: New USB device found, idVendor=1a86, idProduct=7523, bcdDevice= 2.64
[ 98.650618] usb 1-1.3.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 98.650632] usb 1-1.3.1: Product: USB Serial
[ 98.655574] ch341 1-1.3.1:1.0: ch341-uart converter detected
[ 98.662859] usb 1-1.3.1: ch341-uart converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[ 98.740404] usb 1-1.3.3: new full-speed USB device number 56 using xhci_hcd
[ 98.846626] usb 1-1.3.3: New USB device found, idVendor=1a86, idProduct=7523, bcdDevice= 2.64
[ 98.846665] usb 1-1.3.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 98.846682] usb 1-1.3.3: Product: USB Serial
[ 98.851390] ch341 1-1.3.3:1.0: ch341-uart converter detected
[ 98.857119] usb 1-1.3.3: ch341-uart converter now attached to ttyUSB1
[ 101.506550] usb 1-1.3: USB disconnect, device number 54
[ 101.506590] usb 1-1.3.1: USB disconnect, device number 55
[ 101.509393] ch341-uart ttyUSB0: ch341-uart converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
[ 101.509578] ch341 1-1.3.1:1.0: device disconnected
[ 101.511452] usb 1-1.3.3: USB disconnect, device number 56
[ 101.513942] ch341-uart ttyUSB1: ch341-uart converter now disconnected from ttyUSB1
[ 101.514178] ch341 1-1.3.3:1.0: device disconnected
[ 101.740431] usb 1-1.3: new high-speed USB device number 57 using xhci_hcd
[ 101.840978] usb 1-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=214b, idProduct=7250, bcdDevice= 1.00
[ 101.841000] usb 1-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
[ 101.841006] usb 1-1.3: Product: USB2.0 HUB
[ 101.842367] hub 1-1.3:1.0: USB hub found
[ 101.842471] hub 1-1.3:1.0: 4 ports detected
[ 102.128412] usb 1-1.3.1: new full-speed USB device number 58 using xhci_hcd
[ 102.234596] usb 1-1.3.1: New USB device found, idVendor=1a86, idProduct=7523, bcdDevice= 2.64
[ 102.234627] usb 1-1.3.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 102.234640] usb 1-1.3.1: Product: USB Serial
[ 102.237335] ch341 1-1.3.1:1.0: ch341-uart converter detected
[ 102.243286] usb 1-1.3.1: ch341-uart converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[ 102.324434] usb 1-1.3.3: new full-speed USB device number 59 using xhci_hcd
[ 102.430653] usb 1-1.3.3: New USB device found, idVendor=1a86, idProduct=7523, bcdDevice= 2.64
[ 102.430689] usb 1-1.3.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 102.430704] usb 1-1.3.3: Product: USB Serial
[ 102.435907] ch341 1-1.3.3:1.0: ch341-uart converter detected
[ 102.442945] usb 1-1.3.3: ch341-uart converter now attached to ttyUSB1
[ 2216.997473] ch341-uart ttyUSB0: usb_serial_generic_read_bulk_callback - urb stopped: -32
[ 3555.996691] sysctl (4924): drop_caches: 3
[ 3566.611753] sysctl (4933): drop_caches: 3
[ 3947.797640] ch341-uart ttyUSB0: usb_serial_generic_read_bulk_callback - urb stopped: -32
[ 5001.414557] sysctl (5014): drop_caches: 3
[14002.475281] ch341-uart ttyUSB0: usb_serial_generic_read_bulk_callback - urb stopped: -32
[19042.770379] ch341-uart ttyUSB0: usb_serial_generic_read_bulk_callback - urb stopped: -32
[19042.778767] ch341-uart ttyUSB1: usb_serial_generic_read_bulk_callback - urb stopped: -32
```

How can I use Python to catch/check the moment when the port stops working?

I tried `ser.is_open` method, but it didn't work because the method returns `True` even when the port stops working.

And check `fcntl.ioctl(self.fd, termios.FIONREAD, buf_, 1) == -1` also didn't work.

Many thanks in advance for any reply